# installing Autolit library

Tags: robotframework

I am writing robot tests for web testing using Google's Robot Framework with SeleniumLibrary (a test library) , one of my test involves uploading a file from the desktop by clicking on a"Browse" button on the webpage and using the windows file explorer window that pops up to navigate to and select the file ( providing a text path to file is disabled on the website for security reasons.) I have tried digging around but found little on automating this Windows File Explorer action , is there a way I can do this ?

After downloading the AutoIt library and trying to install it is asking for wincom32./python window extensions.And  i am trying to install it is giving some error like

```
Building pywin32 2.7.217.0    
Trace-back (most recent call last):    
  File "setup.py", line1944, in <module>
      """ % dirs).split(),    
  File "setup.py", line 603,    in __init__
      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(sdk_dir, "include", "activdbg.h")):    
  File"C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 96 in join
      assert len(path) > 0    
  TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a quick step to step guide to install autoit for robotframework in Windows (as what versions work with what in python is a pain):

First you will need a 32 bit python as autoit will not install for windows 64bit. I have used:

- Python 2.6

Then from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20217/
Download the windows installer so for python 2.6 it will be:

- pywin32-217.win32-py2.6.exe

Now on the command prompt go to the location of where you downloaded the autoit files ex:
 - cd C:\Development\Downloaded files\AutoItLibrary-1.1
and then type
 - python setup.py install

If successful you will see lines in the cmd line such as:

```
 Generating...
 Importing module
 running install
 running build
 running build_py
 creating build
 creating build\lib
 creating build\lib\AutoItLibrary
 copying src\AutoItLibrary\Counter.py -> build\lib\AutoItLibrary
 copying src\AutoItLibrary\Logger.py -> build\lib\AutoItLibrary
 copying src\AutoItLibrary\__init__.py -> build\lib\AutoItLibrary
 running install_lib
 copying build\lib\AutoItLibrary\Counter.py -> C:\Python26\Lib\site-     packages\AutoItLibrary
 copying build\lib\AutoItLibrary\Logger.py -> C:\Python26\Lib\site-
```

Now run the test
C:\RobotFramework\Extensions\AutoItLibrary\tests

Note: Ensure you have the environment variables set correctly:i.e.
 - c:\python26 for python
 - c:\python26\scripts for pybot

You can now run your robotframework tests by creating an exe and calling
 - Run  C:\RobotFramework\Seans Autoit Files\FF_FileUpload.exe

To find how to create the autoit exe visit the autoit website.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to install the pywin32 extensions from source? There are windows installers for all flavours of windows so I would recommend you install using an installer.

(one other thing, google did not make robot framework. It was Nokia Siemens networks...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Keyword 'Choose File'. No need for AutoIT Lib

Name: Choose File

Source: Selenium2Library

Arguments: [ locator | file_path ]

Inputs the `file_path` into file input field found by `identifier`. 
This keyword is most often used to input files into upload forms. The file specified with `file_path` must be available on the same host where the Selenium Server is running.

Example: Choose File   my_upload_field   C:\Automation\sample.csv

Answer (score 0):

"Choose File" worked in my case. Please note that in my case this made robot write the file path into the input field which was otherwise not editable manually.