# Installing AutoIt for Robot framework

Tags: python, autoit, robotframework

I am trying to install the AutoIt library for Robot Framework, I've tried using the pip command command `pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary` but that didn't work. I then downloaded the [AutoIt library](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/) and installed it but I can't open it.

Why can't I use the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons that your install may not be working correctly:
 1. You haven't installed [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython), which I don't think you have.
 2. You need the 32bit version of [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) installed or AutoIt [won't actually work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748828/installing-autolit-library).

If these fixes don't work, comment and I will try to help further

Answer (score 0):

**Step1.**  Please make sure you have installed autoit-v3-setup.exe, 
pywin32-220.win-amd64-py2.7.exe.
**Step2.**  You have to run "python setup.py install" in a **Administrator** cmd 
while installing AutoItLibrary-1.1.  
**Step.3**  If you meet any porblem, please add the error message, that will be very useful.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but resolved by following the below steps.

1. Download the file from below path "https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-autoitlibrary/#files"
2. Unzip and run the "setup.py" file from the command prompt as administrator by using the below command "python setup.py install".
3. Open your ride editor and import the library with the name "AutoItLibrary".
   It worked for me with below versions

```
robotframework==3.1.2
robotframework-autoitlibrary==1.2.5
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.3.0
robotframework-ride==1.7.4.1
selenium 3.141.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I had some troubles installing the lastest version 1.2.2 which supports python 3 on windows and it was due to blank spaces in the path as Program Files : https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/issues/30 I hope it helps somebody, the fix is basically quotes around the path